# sortBy('time') gives error: time() expects exactly 0 parameters, 2 given in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, collections

I have a collection of Measures

```
$m = new Measure([
                    'time' => $measure['timestamp'],
                    'operation_id' => $measure['op_id'],
                    'meter_id' => $prm,
                    'conso_prod' => $measure['conso_prod'],
                    'delta' => $measure['delta'],
                    'redistributed' => $measure['redistribute'],
                ]
```

`Measure` table is a postgres hypertable(timescaleDB extension)

`time` is a timestamp without timezone

When I want to sort it, I can do it with:

```
$myCollection->sortBy(['operation_id', 'meter_id', 'conso_prod']);
```

But I also want to sort it by timestamp asc.

Now, if I do:

```
$myCollection->sortBy(['operation_id', 'meter_id', 'conso_prod', 'time']);
```

I get an error:

```
time() expects exactly 0 parameters, 2 given
```

Why is it happening ?

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that your `time` key of the array is already a timestamp so I have basically parsed it to a Carbon instance.

```
$myCollection->sortBy(function ($obj, $key) {
    return Carbon::parse($obj['time']);
});
```

Try to use it separately from the array like this,

```
$myCollection->sortBy(['operation_id', 'meter_id', 'conso_prod'])->sortBy(function ($obj, $key) {
    return Carbon::parse($obj['time']);
});
```

Comment: Well, time is a timestamp in Postgres, but the value of $measure['timestamp'] is a string at RFC3339 format : 2020-10-01T00:00:00Z

Comment: ooopps, no it is not working. I have no more error, but it is now sorted by time, and no more by ['operation_id', 'meter_id', 'conso_prod'], and I also have to reapply ->values() to the result

Comment: I will group it by ->groupBy(['operation_id', 'meter_id', 'conso_prod']), and then sort it by time, and it should work !

Comment: I have never tried to sort by 4 things(atmost 1) before, so I guess you have to try it out then you can post here if it worked or not